# Algorithm for solving simultaneous equations

Tags: c++, geometry, linear-algebra

I'm making an mfc application in which I need to deduce if two lines intersect or not. For that I have the 2 equations:

```
x= [-x1y2 +x2y1 - (x2-x1)y ] / y1-y2

y= [-x3y4 +x4y3 - (y3-y4)x ] / x4-x3
```

But I need a way to solve these 2 equations simultaneously, How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to solve a general equation or are you sure there will always be two variables and two equations only?

Comment: @H2CO3 The equations I've given will be general, i.e I'll always have these 2 but with variable values of x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3 and y4.  From these 2 the program will have to calculate the values of x and y each time.

Comment: Are you trying to optimise an enormous number of these equations, or just each loop iteration, you have these two calculations for one set of coordinates [two lines]?

The answer to your question depends on which one of the type of questions you're trying to solve.

Comment: @ Mats Petersson I'm not sure if I understand your question, but in simple terms, the equations always remain the same, all that changes each time is the values for x1,y1....x4,y4 .

Answer (score 2):

OK, assuming that `x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4` are constant inside the process we can also write this as

```
x=a-b*y
y=c-d*x
```

with `a=(-x1y2+x2y1)/y1-y2` etc.

Now substituting the first line into the second gives

```
y=c-d*(a-b*y)
y(1+d*b)=c-d*a
y=(c-d*a)/(1+d*b)
```

resubstituting into `x=a-b*y` gives the x part of the result