# Solving simultaneous equations with C++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to create a program that can solve simultaneous equations. I have this:

```
int main()
{   float a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2;
    float x,y;
    system("CLS");
    printf("We require simultaneous in the form of \n\n\ta1x+b1y=c1\n\n\ta2x+b2y=c2\n");
    printf("enter the values of a1,b1,c1 \n a2,b2,c2\n respectively:\n");
    scanf("%f%f%f%f%f%f",&a1,&b1,&c1,&a2,&b2,&c2);
    printf("The Simultaneous equations are \n %fx+%fy=%f",a1,b1,c1);
    printf("and\n%fx+%fy=%f",a2,b2,c2);
    printf("\n\nThe Solution is=\n");
    y=(((c1*a2)-(c2*a1))/((b1*a2)-(a1*b2)));
    x=((c1-(b1*y))/a1);
    printf(" x = %f",x);
    printf("\n y = %f",y);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And it is working as I expected, however, do I not understand the algorithm for `y` and `x`, can anyone give me another code or explain the current code I have here?

Comment: This is a very vague question, I do not understand what you are asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for solving simultaneous equations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995110/algorithm-for-solving-simultaneous-equations)

Comment: Are you asking us to explain some maths to you? BTW what happens if b1*a2 == a1*b2?

Comment: There is an answer to this in the link above - see if that helps - otherwise take the advice of the comments above.

Comment: Ask http://math.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get the maths

Comment: Wow, so many redundant parentheses! 7 out of 10 pairs!

Answer (score 5):

It's using [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), which is a way to solve simultaneous equations without doing any algebra.

Answer (score 0):

With the code given here, there is no simultaneous solving. The code simply calculates "y" with "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1" & "c2" variables and then it used "y", "a1", "b1" & "c1" to calculate "x". Do you have more information on the context of those equations? (Although I'm new here, I think your question is simply out of scope for this site; It looks more like a math question than a code question.)